# Discord.py функция запуска бота в определенное время каждый день в определенный канал

Tags: python, discord, discord-api, discord.py

Я использую discord.py для создания бота в discord. Цель заключается в том, чтобы в определенное время в дискорд канал в течении каждого дня приходило уведомление о том, что какое-либо событие началось. Пробовал через библиотеки asyncio, datetime, schedler, но никак не получается. Хотел бы, чтобы это работало каждый день и напоминало о важных событиях.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выполнить действие каждый день в какое-то время, но и в определенный канал дискорда, любые сообщения.

Заранее благодарю вас!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать [таски](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html), это должно тебе помочь

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
```